# Timer intervals, Making 1 timer stop another timer -

Tags: c#, timer

Hey guys im trying to get a simple button masher up, What i want timer1 to do is mash keys in richtextbox1 for 30 seconds over and over, after 30 seconds Activate timer2, which will disable timer 1 and press keys in richtextbox 2 once, then wait 10 seconds and activate timer 1 again.

Im extremley new to c# but ive tried using timer 3 to stop timer 2 and start timer 1 again and it just messes it self up. The code ive tried is below. Any help apreciated...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendKeys.Send(richTextBox1.Text);
            SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer2.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendKeys.Send(richTextBox2.Text);
            SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}"); 
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer2.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void richTextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you really fixated on using timers to do this?

Comment: No im not fixed on using timers only, I just thought it was the simplest way of doing it. Im probably wrong though, Have you got some suggestions that could help me do this?

Comment: I think we'll need to know more about what the program is trying to accomplish.

Comment: Its just a button masher like i said above, Like a macro. Hit keys in textbox 1 over and over for 30 seconds, stop, press keys in text box 2 once, wait 10 seconds, then start hitting keys in textbox 1 again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use just one timer, increment a state counter every second, and perform an action base on the current state.

```
public Form1()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    // Just to illustrate - can be done in the designer.
    this.timer.Interval = 1000; // One second.
    this.timer.Enable = true;
}

private Int32 state = 0;

private void timer_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((0 <= this.state) && (this.state < 30)) // Hit text box 1 30 times.
    {
        SendKeys.Send(this.richTextBox1.Text);
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
    }
    else if (this.state == 30) // Hit text box 2 once.
    {
        SendKeys.Send(this.richTextBox2.Text);
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
    }
    else if ((31 <= this.state) && (this.state < 40)) // Do nothing 9 times.
    {
        // Do nothing.
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(); // Unexpected state.
    }

    // Update state.
    this.state = (this.state + 1) % 40;
}
```

The variant with two numeric up down controls.

```
public Form1()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    // Just to illustrate - can be done in the designer.
    this.timer.Interval = 1000; // One second.
    this.timer.Enable = true;
}

private Int32 state = 0;

private void timer_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Decimal n1 = this.numericUpDown1.Value;
    Decimal n2 = this.numericUpDown2.Value;

    if ((0 <= this.state) && (this.state < n1))
    {
        SendKeys.Send(this.richTextBox1.Text);
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
    }
    else if (this.state == n1)
    {
        SendKeys.Send(this.richTextBox2.Text);
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
    }
    else if ((n1 <= this.state) && (this.state < n1 + n2))
    {
        // Do nothing.
    }
    else
    {
        // Reset state to resolve race conditions.
        this.state = 0;
    }

    // Update state.
    this.state = (this.state + 1) % (n1 + n2);
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for that, it works almost the way i want it to. Using the method above it hits the keys in richtexbox1 only once, then waits 30 seconds and hits keys in textbox2. i need it to hit keys from textbox1 over and over for 30 seconds, what would i add in there to do this ?

Comment: What frequency do you want during the 30 seconds?

Comment: every 1 second should be fine. But it has to be only for the text in textbox 1.

Comment: I still have no clue what you want to achieve, but I can tell you how to do it ... :D Going to update my answer.

Comment: Hey mate thats pretty much exactly what i was looking for! works pretty good now!, dont want to push my luck but any chance you can point me in the right direct to see how i can add a texbox so i can type the interval in there and run it? so that the 30 seconds and 10 seconds can be changed on the fly ?

if this is possible?

Comment: Don't use text boxes, use two NumericUpDownControls. Replace (this.state < 30) and (this.state == 30) with numericUpDown1.Value, (31 <= this.state) with numericUpDown1.Value + 1, and (this.state < 40) and (this.state + 1) % 40 with numericUpDown1.Value + numericUpDown2.Value. Instead of throwing the exception, you should set this.state to zero to avoid race conditions.

Comment: Hey thanks. This is what ive done, Does it look correct.

 if ((0 <= this.state) && numericUpDown1.Value) // Hit text box 1 30 times.

else if (numericUpDown1.Value + 1 && numericUpDown1.Value + numericUpDown2.Value) // Do nothing 9 times.

   // Update state.
            this.state = (numericUpDown1.Value + 1 && numericUpDown1.Value + numericUpDown2.Value);

Do i delete " else if (this.state == 30) // Hit text box 2 once. "

Comment: I also have 3 errors. #1 : Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'decimal' #2 is the same, and #3 is Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'decimal'

#1 comes up at : else if (numericUpDown1.Value + 1 && numericUpDown1.Value + numericUpDown2.Value)// Do nothing 9 times.

#2 comes up at : this.state = (numericUpDown1.Value + 1 && numericUpDown1.Value + numericUpDown2.Value);

#3 comes up at : if ((0 <= this.state) && numericUpDown1.Value) // Hit text box 1 30 times.

Comment: Hey man thanks alot!, I changed it and i get 1 error now. //// Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) /// This comes up @     // Update state.
    this.state = (this.state + 1) % (n1 + n2);

Sorry to be such a hassle! thanks again for the help

Comment: oh also i tried removing the update state section that causes the error, it gets rid of the error but then what ever i put into textbox2 is ignored and only textbox 1 is pressed.

Comment: Just add an explicit cast to the state update ...  this.state = (this.state + 1) % (Int32)(n1 + n2);

Answer (score 1):

If timer3 is running continuously, won't it start timer1 and stop timer2 at unpredictable times, without warning?

IOW, what starts and stops timer3?

As JustLoren pointed out, there might be a cleaner way to do this.  Perhaps a single timer event and some controlling logic and flags, rather than trying to juggle three timers.

Comment: Yeah, using a lot of timers is usually a sign that the code can be simplified greatly.